# ASP.NET Core 6 identityserver (duende) : no DefaultAuthenticateScheme found or no CookieAuthenticationScheme configured on IdentityServerOptions

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

So here's our setup. we have

- Angular web app
- Identity server API (ASP.NET Core 6, duende identity server)

Identity server config in `Program.cs`:

```
    builder.Services
        .AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

    builder.Services
        .AddIdentityServer(options =>
        {
            options.Events.RaiseErrorEvents = true;
            options.Events.RaiseInformationEvents = true;
            options.Events.RaiseFailureEvents = true;
            options.Events.RaiseSuccessEvents = true;

            // see https://docs.duendesoftware.com/identityserver/v6/fundamentals/resources/
            options.EmitStaticAudienceClaim = true;
            options.IssuerUri = configuration["IssuerUri"];
        })
        .AddConfigurationStore(options =>
        {
            options.ConfigureDbContext = b =>
                b.UseMySql(conString, serverVersion, sqlOptions => sqlOptions.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));
        })
        .AddOperationalStore(options =>
        {
            options.ConfigureDbContext = b =>
            {
                b.UseMySql(conString, serverVersion, sqlOptions => sqlOptions.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));
            };
        })
        .AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>();
    
    builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options => {
            options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultForbidScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultSignOutScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
return builder.Build();
```

Then after that, we call

```
app.useAuthorization();
    app.useAuthentication();
```

When the web app is trying to get the openid configuration from the identity server url (/.well-known/openid-configuration), we are getting this error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: No DefaultAuthenticateScheme found or no CookieAuthenticationScheme configured on IdentityServerOptions.
>
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.AuthenticationManagerExtensions.GetCookieAuthenticationSchemeAsync(HttpContext context) in /*/src/IdentityServer/Extensions/HttpContextAuthenticationExtensions.cs:line 54
>
> at Duende.IdentityServer.Services.DefaultUserSession.AuthenticateAsync() in /*/src/IdentityServer/Services/Default/DefaultUserSession.cs:line 135
> at Duende.IdentityServer.Services.DefaultUserSession.GetSessionIdAsync() in /*/src/IdentityServer/Services/Default/DefaultUserSession.cs:line 215
>
> at Duende.IdentityServer.Services.DefaultUserSession.EnsureSessionIdCookieAsync() in /*/src/IdentityServer/Services/Default/DefaultUserSession.cs:line 226
> at Duende.IdentityServer.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context, IEndpointRouter router, IUserSession session, IEventService events, IIssuerNameService issuerNameService, IBackChannelLogoutService backChannelLogoutService) in /*/src/IdentityServer/Hosting/IdentityServerMiddleware.cs:line 55
>
> at Duende.IdentityServer.Hosting.MutualTlsEndpointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context, IAuthenticationSchemeProvider schemes) in /*/src/IdentityServer/Hosting/MutualTlsEndpointMiddleware.cs:line 94
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
> at Duende.IdentityServer.Hosting.DynamicProviders.DynamicSchemeAuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) in /*/src/IdentityServer/Hosting/DynamicProviders/DynamicSchemes /DynamicSchemeAuthenticationMiddleware.cs:line 47
>
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsMiddleware.g__InvokeCoreAwaited|15_0(HttpContext context, Task`1 policyTask)
>
> at Duende.IdentityServer.Hosting.BaseUrlMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) in /*/src/IdentityServer/Hosting/BaseUrlMiddleware.cs:line 27
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

Answer (score 4):

I checked your codes and found two mistakes:

1,if you are using cookie authentication,and setted as below:
[image]

you need to modify your codes as below:

```
    builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options => 
     {
        ......
     })
   .AddCookie( "Cookies",options =>
    {
        ......;
    })
```

2,you need to move the codes:

```
app.useAuthentication();
```

in front of

```
app.useAuthorization();
```

You could modify your codes and try again,and if you could share more codes related,I could test for you

**Update :**
try to set your IdentityServer Auth Options:

```
builder.Services
        .AddIdentityServer(options =>
        {
            ......
            options.Authentication.CookieAuthenticationScheme= ....
            options.Authentication.CookieLifetime = .....
            .....
        });
```

You could follow the document:
http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/reference/options.html#authentication

Comment: this doesn't seem to work locally and even when deployed in azure aks. we are not using https in azure. any idea?

Comment: I've updated my answer,please check it

Comment: `UseAuthentication`, `UseRouting`, `UseIdentityServer`, `UseAuthorization`, `UseEndpoints` ([See also](https://github.com/PieterjanDeClippel/SSO/blob/master/Central/Sso.Central/Startup.cs#L63))

Comment: using https now. still doesn't seem to work properly. hahaha damn this is hell, why is it so hard to configure.